# How do I validate XML against XSD (separate documents) in DNX Core 5.0 (ASP.NET 5)?

Tags: validation, xsd, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I am porting some code to ASP.NET 5, and want to target DNX Core 5.0. However, I am having trouble locating the types that are required to validate an XML document against an XSD document.

Here is the code:

```
var xsdStream = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(xsdPath);
using (XmlReader xsd = XmlReader.Create(xsdStream))
{
    XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schema.Add(null, xsd);

    XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();

    xmlReaderSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    xmlReaderSettings.Schemas.Add(schema);

    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, xmlReaderSettings))
    {
        try
        {
            while (xmlReader.Read());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format(Resources.Messages.XmlValidationFailed, xmlPath), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, all I want is to stop on the first error and throw an exception indicating what the error is.

The problems are:

1. The `XmlSchemaSet` class doesn't exist in the `System.Xml.Schema` namespace (or anywhere else I have found).
2. The `XmlReaderSettings.ValidationType` and `XmlReaderSettings.Schemas` properties do not exist.

I checked the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387037.aspx) which has a slightly different approach. However, as before `XmlSchemaSet` doesn't exist, and neither does `XDocument.Validate()`. I have also searched several of the [ASP.NET projects](https://github.com/aspnet) for an example but can't seem to find any.

What facilities (if any) exist in DNX Core 5.0 to validate XML against an XSD? I would prefer to do this using streams if possible, but if absolutely necessary I will accept an approach that reads the entire documents into memory at once.

Comment: Does not seem like XSD is part of CoreClr - https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src. You may want to file a bug in their repo...

Comment: @Pawel - Thanks for the tip. Opened a new issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3633).

Comment: @Pawel might want to change your comment to answer so it can be voted and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for XSD in the first release. When I heard right in one of the tweets, posts, bugs or community standups they do, it is considered for a later release.

ps: Pawel should answer this and get the credits ... but we should close this question.